# Can't find my Wifi in the list of available networks

Tags: networking

After running `sudo lshw -c network` I get this, that has to do with my adapter:

```
 *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Qualcomm Atheros
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 31
       serial: 54:8c:a0:90:fb:45
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.8.0-41-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:132 memory:b4200000-b43fffff
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you change your channel from 13 or 14 to e.g. 6 or 7?

Comment: Is this an answer to the OP?

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Is there some way to make it work in 13, because there so many wifi signals in channel 6 and my wifi gets messed up

Comment: Yes it was. In north america you can go to channel 11, in europe to 13 and in Japan to channel 14.

Comment: So if I am in Europe how do I do it? I've searched the web and there isn't a clear way to do it.

Comment: @N.Kotarelas what is the output of `sudo iw reg get`?

Comment: @Seth It was something like DE-00 or something like that but I changed it to my region with `sudo iw reg set` but the problem wasn't resolved.